# jQuery variable change

Tags: jquery, variables, timer, delay

I'm learning jQuery. I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var status = false;
$("#red").click(function() {
    if(status == false) {
        $("#red").animate({
            width: "800px",
            height: "800px"
        }, 1000);
        $("#text").delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
        status = true;

    }
    else if(status == true) {
        $("#text").fadeTo(1000, 0.0);
        $("#red").delay(1000).animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px"
        }, 1000);
        status = false;
    }
});
```

});

Now, I want the clicks to not stack. I thought of changing the variable "status" value only after one second, then the clicks won't stack. How can I do it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a global variable to a state when the animation has completed and add an additional argument to the if: -

```
var check;

$(document).ready(function () {
var status = false;
$("#red").click(function() {
if(status == false && check == true) {
    $("#red").animate({
        width: "800px",
        height: "800px"
    }, 1000, function() {
     // Animation complete.
     check = true;

     });


    $("#text").delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
    status = true;

}
else if(status == true && check == true) {
    $("#text").fadeTo(1000, 0.0);
    $("#red").delay(1000).animate({
        width: "200px",
        height: "200px"
    }, 1000, , function() {
     // Animation complete.
     check = true;

     });
    status = false;
}
```

});

Comment: No need for the global var then, I just set the value of "status" after completion of the animation. Works like a charm, thanks dude!

Comment: No worries man, glad to be of service, maybe you could mark as answer? :D